# Angular 2 Unit test Router Navigation

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Is there a way to UNIT test a router route?

I'm using Sinon to create spys and stubs.

The component

```
onSubmit(value: Authentication){
        this.authenticateService.getTokenFromServer(value).subscribe(v => {
            const token = this.tokenService.getToken();
            if(token){
                this.router.navigate([Config.videoPage]);

            }
        });
    }
```

Test

```
let router: any;
beforeEach(() => {
        router = createStubInstance(Router);

     it('(onSubmit() send user form to server)', () => {
            sut.onSubmit({name: 'Abc', password: '123'});
            expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/video']);
        });
```

Comment: The main goal of unit testing is just to check if the router navigation has been called or not. Verifying actual navigation could be the part of e2e testing.

Comment: That sounds correct. Should I just try something in line with 
`(router.navigate.calledOnce).toBe(true);` ?

Comment: You can do : `expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main goal of **unit testing** is just to check if the **router navigation** has been called or not. Verifying actual navigation could be the part of **e2e testing**.

To check for the url to which the router has navigated :

```
expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/video']);
```

If you want to check the number of times the navigation has happend within each spec:

```
expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
```

**EDIT** :

Creating mock router :

```
let router = {
            navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate'),    // to spy on the url that has been routed
        };
```

and in `providers` section of `TestBed` Configuration, add this :

```
providers: [{provide: Router, useValue: router}]
```

Comment: `Expected a spy, but got Function` is the error I'm getting

Comment: Looks like spy is not created properly. Check updated answer.